# WCF Rest Services And User Info Persistence

Tags: .net, wcf, cookies, wcf-rest

I was trying to persist a logged in user as a cookie through a WCF Rest Service.  I setup the cookie like follows, through a component that the WCF rest service uses:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("Key");
.
.
cookie.HttpOnly = true;

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

But the cookie, when retrieved, later on is null:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("Key"); //returns null
```

Is cookie not a good way of doing this for WCF rest services, or is there another way to do it?

**EDIT**: I should note I'm using the same component for a web site, and it's working great for it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more context around where this code? Is this inside WCF service method? Why are you persisting he logged in user?

Comment: @PetarVucetin Yes, I have a component inside the WCF rest service.  I need a user to first login, and a lot of the REST method are related to the logged in user, and only return that user's information.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you need to have [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)] attribute on your service to access the HttpContext [MSDN details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsattribute.aspx)